# Parsing and creating XML documents within applets

Tags: java, applet, xml-parsing

I have a need to generate and parse XML documents within an applet.   The question is how to do this.   I can write java code to produce XML formatted documents.   I've done this in the past.   I can also use any number of parsers to parse the XML document.    What I am wondering is whether XMLbeans or a similar package will work.    A quick search on the internet revealed that XMLbeans does not work from within an applet, but the posts were from 5 years ago.   Does anyone know if this is fixed?    I have a particular concern about referencing the XML schema from within the applet, upon which XMLbeans depends.

Is this a fruitful path to pursue or should I go back to relying on tried and true methods describe in the first part of this post?

Comment: Also, if you don't feel like writing XMl deserialisation code by hand, try `XStream` (which seems to have some degree of support for running under appled security restrictions).

Comment: Any pure Java XML API that uses offers `URL` or `InputStream` access can be used in an applet.  If the XML or any requested schema is on the home domain, the applet can be sand-boxed.  Otherwise it will need to be digitally signed and trusted.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that XMLbeans does work within applets.    You just need to put the xbean.jar and the jar that xmlbeans generates from the xsd in the ARCHIVE attribute of the APPLET tag like you would any jar you wish to download into the applet.